# Why should I use an std::unique_ptr when I could just destroy the object in my destructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor, unique-ptr

Say I have this class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        bar = new Bar;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        if(bar)
            delete bar;
    }
private:
    Bar* bar;

};
```

Why would I want to use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers when `unique_ptr` is bloated? Are there any advantage? Is there any situation where my destructor won't be called?

Comment: In what way is `std::unique_ptr` bloated? It's a very thin wrapper around a raw pointer.

Comment: My friend says "You're calling an extra constructor and an extra destructor"

Comment: Because you'll forget.  maybe not now, but later.   You'll change something and forget to change something else.  Now you have a memory leak.  Or you'll double free it.  Also, it's not "bloated"

Comment: To prove a point, look at how much this constructor and getter function is costing me [here](https://godbolt.org/g/bYoMvu). Notice that the compiler simply loads the value and prints it, completely optimizing out any references to my class. And that's ignoring the fact that a constructor call to copy 8 bytes would be completely negligible in nearly every situation.

Comment: Your friend is prematurely optimizing, and their code is going to be a piece of crap because of it. Write clean code, use the language to help you get it right.

Comment: In my tests the *unique pointer* was equally as fast as a *raw pointer* and when examining the generated assembly language the compiler had generated identical code when dereferencing a *unique pointer* an a *raw pointer*. The optimizer had removed the `std::unique_ptr` entirely when dereferencing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The code you have above actually has a bug because you haven't defined a copy constructor or assignment operator. Imagine this code:

```
Foo one;
Foo two = one;
```

Because `two` is a copy of `one`, it's initialized using the default copy constructor - which makes both `bar` pointers point to the same object. This means that when the destructor for `two` fires, it will deallocate the same object shared by `one`, so `one`'s destructor will trigger undefined behavior. Oops.

Now, if you didn't want to make your object copyable, you could say that explicitly like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        bar = new Bar;
    }
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator= (const Foo&) = delete;

    ~Foo()
    {
        if(bar)
            delete bar;
    }
private:
    Bar* bar;

};
```

So that fixes that problem - but look at the amount of code involved! You had to explicitly delete two functions and write a destructor by hand.

Except there's another problem. Suppose I do this:

```
Foo one;
Foo two = std::move(one);
```

This initializes `two` by moving the contents of `one` into `two`. Or does it? Unfortunately, the answer is no, because the default move constructor will default to moving the pointer, which just does a straight pointer copy. So now you get the same thing as before. Oops.

Not to worry! We can fix this by defining a custom move constructor and move assignment operator:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        bar = new Bar;
    }
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator= (const Foo&) = delete;

    Foo(Foo&& rhs)
    {
        bar = rhs.bar;
        rhs.bar = nullptr;
    }

    Foo& operator= (Foo&& rhs)
    {
        if (bar != rhs.bar)
        {
            delete bar;
            bar = rhs.bar;
            rhs.bar = nullptr;
        }
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        if(bar)
            delete bar;
    }
private:
    Bar* bar;

};
```

Phew! That's a *ton* of code, but at least it's correct. (Or is it?)

On the other hand, imagine you wrote this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : bar(new Bar) {
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar;
};
```

Wow, that's a lot shorter! And it automatically ensures that the class can't be copied, *and* it makes the default move constructor and move assignment operators work correctly.

So one huge advantage of `std::unique_ptr` is that it automatically handles resource management, yes, but another one is that it plays nicely with copy and move semantics and doesn't work in unexpected ways. That's one of the main reasons to use it. You can say what you mean - "I'm the only one who should know about this thing, and you can't share it" - and the compiler will enforce it for you. Enlisting the compiler to help you avoid mistakes is almost always a good idea.

As for bloat - I'd need to see evidence of that. `std::unique_ptr` is a thin wrapper on a pointer type and a good optimizing compiler should have no trouble generating good code for it. True, there's the constructor, destructor, etc. associated with `std::unique_ptr`, but a reasonable compiler will inline those calls, which essentially just do the same thing as what you had initially described.

Comment: is it ok if I laugh.. just a little bit?  "But my example is soo easy".. and yet the poster still messed it up.

Comment: Thanks! This clears it up.

also yeah, i just quickly wrote up op lol

Comment: my friend is getting mad, "I have yet to see an answer that's anything other than "because I'm too lazy to avoid using STL""

Comment: @Snorflake I'm not sure what your friend means by that. I don't think the above answer has anything to do with being lazy. (Also, to be really pedantic, but hopefully in an instructive way: the term "STL" usually refers to things like `std::vector` and `std::map` that were originally part of a library called STL but which has since been incorporated (in part) into the language. I wouldn't really call `std::unique_ptr` a part of the STL.)

Comment: @Snorflake I assume your friend also uses raw `char*`s and writes their own dynamic array implementation every time they need one.  You use the standard library because they're solved problems.  Why solve them yourself every time you write a new program?

Comment: he said this, ``: I use std::map in certain situations, and I only ever use std::string as a key type for std::map (because it doesn't work with const char*)``

Comment: Your friend has an odd aversion to simple solutions to everyday problems.

Comment: @Snorflake The reason why `const char*`s don't work as keys in a `std::map` is actually really enlightening and explains one of the reasons why `std::string` is such a nice thing to have lying around. See if you can find a good explanation for that on the site!

Comment: @Snorflake: "*because I'm too lazy to avoid using STL*" There are genuine reasons to avoid using any particular elements of the standard library. But to claim that using good, well-tested, and highly useful code is *laziness* is flat-out absurd. This person seems impervious to reason, so I would advise you to simply not listen to their advice.

Comment: @Snorflake: Stop taking advice from this friend, they are a blight to software. `std::map` works for `const char*` just fine. Maybe they want to treat their `const char*` as C-strings, then they believe it doesn't work? Except it still does, as long as you provide it a `Compare` class for treating `const char*` as C-strings (ya know, because the language isn't magic and has no reason to treat every `const char*` as a null-terminated string, hence why you need to tell it). Etc. This person doesn't know what they're doing.

Answer (score 4):

You are basically relying on a class to manage a pointer's lifetime, but neglect to consider that pointers get passed between functions, returned from functions, and generally exist everywhere. What if the pointer in your example needs to outlive the class? What if it needs to be deleted before the class is destroyed?

Consider this function:

```
Bar * doStuff(int param) {
    return new Bar(param);
}
```

You now have a dynamically allocated object that may leak if you forget to delete it. Perhaps you didn't read the documentation, or perhaps the documentation is lacking. Regardless, this function puts an unnecessary burden on you to destroy the the returned instance of `Bar`.

Now consider:

```
std::unique_ptr<Bar> doStuffBetter(int param) {
    return new Bar(param);
}
```

The returned `unique_ptr` manages the lifetime of the pointer it wraps. The fact that the function returns a `unique_ptr` eliminates any confusion about ownership and lifetime. Once the returned `unique_ptr` goes out of scope and its destructor called, the instance of `Bar` is automatically deleted.

`unique_ptr` is just one of several methodologies that the standard library provides to make using pointers a less messy process and express ownership. It is both lightweight and works largely like a normal pointer, save for copying.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to be exception-safe by using `std::unique_ptr` (RAII) instead of raw pointers.

Consider a class has two member variables acquiring memory in its constructor.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        bar = new Bar;
        car = new Car;    // <- What happens when this throws exception?
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        if(bar)
            delete bar;
        if(car)
            delete car;
    }
private:
    Bar* bar;
    Car* car;

};
```

If the constructor of `Foo` throws exception, `Foo` is not successfully constructed, therefore its destructor is not called.
When `new Car` throws exception, `bar` is not deleted, so there will be a memory leak.

Now consider the code using `std::unique_ptr`.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : bar(std::make_unique<Bar>()), car(std::make_unique<Car>()) {}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar;
    std::unique_ptr<Car> car;

};
```

If the constructor of `Foo` throws exception, `Foo` is not successfully constructed, therefore its destructor is not called.
However, destructors of successfully created member instances are called.
Even `std::make_unique<Car>()` throws exception, destructor of `bar` is called, so there will be no memory leak.